# Update multiple fields based on mulitple values

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, insert-update

I have a little issue that I can't figure out, basically a user fills in a form, this data saves into a table, but i have another table where based on some values will update a value in that table to yes.

So for example in my form i have value1, value2, value3, value4. all of which are drop down menus with values in that save into a field of the same name in table1.

Now in table2 i have a field called spaces, and spacetaken. Each has of these values in this table has corresponds its id to that of value1/2/3/4 fields in tabl1. I hope i explained that ok.

Now basically when i save a value i want it to update spacetaken to yes, so for example value1 could be 44, value2 could be 55 and both were selected in drop down and saved to table1, now i want to update table2 spacetaken to yes where spaces = value1 and value2

I have this so far

```
UPDATE table2 SET spacetaken='yes' WHERE spaces='value1' AND spaces='value2'
```

this doesnt work.

but

```
UPDATE table2 SET spacetaken='yes' WHERE spaces='value1'
```

will set the space with id same as value1 to taken - yes, basically i want a way to set spacestaken to yes based on multiple values.

Sorry if i didnt explain this very well.

Thanks in advance.

Ian

Comment: Use `or` like: `WHERE spaces='value1' or spaces='value2'`

Answer (score 2):

How can your value be'value1' **AND** 'value2' at the same time?

Try using **OR** instead...

Comment: well, the value1 and value2 corresponds to spaces value, therefore if the user has selected value1 and value2 into table1, i need the spaces which id is the same as value1 and value2 to be set to yes. Boht not one or the other.

Comment: I see, i taken the maeing of OR as in one or the other. Thankyou OR works great

Comment: A boolean OR will match all rows where at least one of the criteria is equatable to true. In this case you are looking for instances where your `spaces` column is equal to 'value1' or 'value2'.  The functionality that you expected is actually what happens when you use `AND`, hence your original problem.  With `AND`, all listed criteria must equate to true and so it was attempting to find a string which was both 'value1' and 'value2' at the same time.  Because 'value1'!='value2' then the criteria is impossible and so will never return any rows.

Answer (score 1):

Use OR here

```
UPDATE table2 SET spacetaken='yes' WHERE spaces='value1' OR spaces='value2'
```

**OR**

```
UPDATE table2 SET spacetaken='yes' WHERE spaces IN ('value1','value2')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table2 SET spacetaken='yes' WHERE spaces='value1' OR spaces='value2'
```